# In case I do not get answers tools for this question and wish to program/ automate for this, which site should I go and post to?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, sql, scripts

Consider this question on Super User:

*[Strategy & Steps to whitelist Chrome cookies for Sites whose logins & passwords are saved?](https://superuser.com/questions/960019)*

Essentially, mapping an exported [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) list towards creating a whitelist for cookie management.

Should I formulate an approach/ script/ program via...?

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)
- [Server Fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Fault)
- [Software Quality Assurance & Testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/tour)

It could possibly be a mix/ mid point between them?

Or another Stack Exchange site?